# Java Pojos - Setter-Call (Field Touched) Detection

Tags: java, validation, dto, pojo

Pojos are often used as Models/DTOs for inserting/updating data into a database.

They need to by validated (with a Validator) to make sure they only contain the expected fields for the use-case:

- insert (all fields must be validated and inserted)
- update (only changed/modified fields must be validated and updated into the database)

To make this possible, it would be helpful if the Java-Language already contains a mechanism to track 'modified' in pojos. A 'modified' for a field would be:

- a setter for a field has been called.

Can someone help me solve such a setter-call detection, with as less boilerplate as possible?

---

Here an example of how i solved it with boilerplate, by letting the Pojos extend a common class:

```java
public abstract class AbstractDTO {

    private Map<String, Object> modifiedFields = new HashMap<>();

    public AbstractDTO() {
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    protected void setAt(String key, Object value) {
        this.modifiedFields.put(key, value);
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    public void resetModifiedFields() {
        this.modifiedFields.clear();
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    public Map<String, Object> getModifiedFields() {
        return this.modifiedFields;
    }
}
```

Impl:

```java
public class Product extends AbstractDTO {

    private Long productId;

    public Long getProductId() {
        return this.productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.setAt("productId", productId);
    }
```

That way i can now check for modified-fields:

```java
boolean isModified = pojo.getModifiedFields().containsKey(field.getName());
```

I also have found an additional way with help of reflection (which helps that my setters only need to call a `touch()` method in the parent:

```java
 public void touch () {
        StackWalker walker = StackWalker.getInstance(RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE);
        StackWalker.StackFrame frame = walker.walk(frames -> {
            Iterator<StackWalker.StackFrame> it = frames.iterator();
            StackWalker.StackFrame a = it.next();
            return it.next();
        });
        String methodName = frame.getMethodName();
        try {
            String withoutSet = methodName.substring(3);
            String fieldname = Character.toLowerCase(withoutSet.charAt(0)) + withoutSet.substring(1);
            Class<?> declaringClass = frame.getDeclaringClass();
            Field field = frame.getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredField(fieldname);

            String getterName = "get" + withoutSet;
            Method getter = declaringClass.getMethod(getterName);
            Object value = getter.invoke(this);
            this.modifiedFields.put(field.getName(), value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to find field!");
        }
    }
```

if someone has any idea how i could call this "touch()" function automatically (behind-the-scenes) when the setter is called, this could also help.

Comment: Recommendations for libraries are considered off-topic for SO, there is a site - [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) specifically for this purpose. That being said I would implement observer/listener pattern to decouple the logic of listening for changes away from the DTOs.

Comment: @Chaosfire thanks, i changed my question to not ask for software recommendations. Observer/Listener pattern sounds good. If someone can provide an example for something like this, it sounds like a boilerplate-free approach.

Comment: Implementing it yourself probably won't be boilerplate free, but maybe you could use the in-built APIs. The old one ([Observable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)) has been deprecated since java 9, but it points towards [java.beans](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html) for better event model, maybe it can be of use.

Comment: when i look at java.beans i see the PropertyChangeListener. But all examples i found are producing more boilerplate than my own implementation with the HashMap approach here in this thread. Maybe i need to try out AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) extensions of Java to make this possible, but they look a bit too invasive. Maybe i just stick with my approach which is since 10 years the same approach. I wonder if there is any need in the Java Ecosystem for this, or why noone has made Pojos more helpful for Change-Detection. Sorry i start to ramble :)

Comment: @Chaosfire why do you think the changes should be decoupled away from the DTOs. I think its most convenient when they are part of the DTOs, because then i can build abstractions that work on the DTOs and handle inserts/updates into the database accordingly to the existance of field-chang-markers in the dtos.

Comment: Because of single responsibility. Yes, it's convenient, but it just feels wrong to me for the DTO to track those changes. It seems that you are using those to trigger partial (patch-like) updates in the database. The natural flow (for me) is that the DTO will notify listener/s about the changes, when there are no more changes to be applied the listener will pass the data to something else to build the queries and so on.

Comment: yes exactly, patch-like updates to the database is the main-intention. Maybe i need to think in the bigger-picture again. Maybe the frontend can send patch-like updated with specific endpoints and Pojos that only contain the fields for the patch-like update (slim pojo with only 1 field or something like this).

Comment: If the frontend is aware of the previous state of the object, maybe you could use [JsonPatch](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-json-patch).

Comment: hm, one of the goals is that the frontend does not need to be aware of the previous state. I want to avoid unnecessary roundtripping of data between the server and frontend.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have something like [Javers](https://javers.org) in mind. Note that change tracking libraries typically require that you have access to the the original version of the object, so make sure that you keep that around without making changes.

Comment: Thank you, i will take a good look at Javers! For performance-reasons i don't want to get the original version of the object. The use-case is: Frontend sends a JSON-Object to the Backend. The JSON-Object contains some Fields of the Model (not all). The JSON-Object is deserialized to the Model (Pojo). The Pojo can tell me which fields have been given from the JSON, and which fields have been left untouched.

Answer (score 1):

With AspectJ an Interceptor can be written, that intercepts any "set*" function calls on Subclasses of AbstractDTO "behind-the-scenes".

```java
public aspect TouchAspect {
    pointcut setterMethodCall(AbstractDTO dto):
        execution(* org.fk.codegen.dto.AbstractDTO+.set*(..)) && target(dto);

    before(AbstractDTO dto): setterMethodCall(dto) {
        dto.touch();
    }
}
```